# is All threads will start in same time in java concurrency programming?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

In my program i am creating 2 tasks. These tasks implement the `Callable` interface. I am  passing these to 2 threads to execute Thread pool class. My question is will these 2 threads start in same time? In java concurrency programming do all threads will start at same time?

Comment: This begs the question -- how can this be of any relevance? If you start a few threads in a loop, you can count on all of them running pretty soon after that. What guarantees do you exactly need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> in java concurrency programming all threads will start in same time?

No they won't.  There is nothing you can do with conventional Java SE to force two threads to start at the same time.  (Indeed, if you don't have a multi-core processor, it is physically impossible for two threads to start at the same time.)

Comment: Only one thing to add: if the requirements are relaxed a bit than one can use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html to make all the Threads wait for some condition before proceeding.

Comment: Thanks stephen, rekin.. i wrote sample program and printing current time in run methods.Both threads are showing same time like : Running serviceProviderID=1 at 02/07/2012 04:57:51
Running serviceProviderID=2 at 02/07/2012 04:57:51

Comment: @rev it's only the same second, not necessarily the same time!

Comment: @Rekin Even if they wait on a condition, the only guarantee is that no thread will run **any sooner** than the condition is met. So we are at the square one.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Exactly, that what i meant by relaxing the requirements.

Comment: @rev There are about 3 billion clock cycles in a second on a 3 GHz CPU. If they start at the same second, that means within 3 billion clock cycles.

Comment: @Rekin The requirements would have to be relaxed by a very precise amount indeed if they are to accept your improvement, but not a simple `for (Thread t : threads) t.start();`. That was my point.

Comment: How can display other threads result if one of threads consumes more time to execute a webservice? can i specify execution time of thread, if that thread not execeuted in specified time can i display other threds result in jsp?

Comment: @rev - I don't really understand what you are asking, but the answer is probably that the JSP (or whatever) has to wait until all of the child threads have finished.  One way to do this is to call `Thread.join(...)` on each of the child threads.

Comment: My question is thread-1 executing task-1 method and thread-2 executing task-2 method both threads are running inparallel. If thread-1 takes more time to process the request, i have cancelle that thread-1 then have to continue execution with thread-2. my situation thread-2 not starting the execution until thread-1 finishes.  my sample code http://jsfiddle.net/hari034/cdUca/

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to start at about the same time, there are several constructs that can help you.

You can use a CyclicBarrier - you create a new CyclicBarrier with 2 permits.
Then each thread calls cbarrier.await() - neither thread will proceed until both have called await, which gives you pretty close to simultaneous execution, which is what I believe you want.

Also, In Java 7, there is a Phaser, which can do pretty much the same thing, but is supposed to be much more performant.